# Mesh lab 2016, where is the light icon gone

Tags: meshlab

There used to be a light bulb icon in the tool bar, no longer in 2016. Any idea where it is now?
And the previous version had the option to activate backface culling, enabling the camera to see through the from face into the object. Can't fin in Meshlab 2016.

Answer (score 8):

In MeshLab 2016.12 the button for turning on/off lighting is no more in the toolbar, but it is (a bit buried) among the shading options of the surface: it is the "none" button.

[image]

If you think that it is really annoying, please raise an issue on github for having it again in the toolbar...